# Проблема сериализации объектов питона pytorch save/load

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Обучил сетку. сохраняю веса `torch.save( model.state_dict(),'/path/to/mydoc/model_w.pt' )`
Все это происходит в гугл колабе. Если  загружать  с помощью `torch.load` в гугл колаб, то проблем нет. Веса опять загружаются в сетку.
Но если я скачиваю файлик себе на комп и пытаюсь его считать  с помощью `torch.load` , то пробрасывает ошибку

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
> 2128: character maps to undefined

НО
если просто создать какой-то тензор любой единичный или какой угодно, так же сохранить его, так же скачать на компьютер себе, все идеально загрузится. Я не знаю что мне делать. Помогите пожалуйста)